# Не удается переименовать столбцы в таблице Python

Tags: python, pandas, rename

Не получается переименовать столбцы.Я получила файл, где первая строка таблицы стала названием колонок, поэтому использовала
`user_companys = pd.read_csv('user_companys-2.csv', header=None)`

Столбцы получи таким образом названия от 0 до 10
На к ним невозможно обратиться или переименовать
`user_companys['3']` дает ошибку при обращении к колонке

`user_companys = user_companys.rename(columns = {'2' : 'name'})`
тоже не дает результат

`user_companys.drop(['1'], axis=1) KeyError: "['1'] not found in axis"`

Answer (score 1):

В своем коде вы указали параметр `header=None` , из за этого заголовки столбцов указываются иначе, не как в оригинальном csv, так что использовать их надо без кавычек, то есть чтобы вывести 4ый столбец используйте `user_companys[3]` , также можно заменить, для этого тоже не используйте кавычки:

```
user_companys = user_companys.rename(columns = {2 : 'name'})
```

Или просто не используйте параметр `header` :

```
user_companys = pd.read_csv('user_companys-2.csv')
```

Затем вы сможете посмотреть названия столбцов, и при необходимости изменить их с помощью `.rename()`

Также советую учесть, то, что заголовки из оригинального csv не пропали, они просто стали первой строкой датафрейма с индексом 0, не забудьте их удалить, иначе они могут мешать работе с данными, так как по сути будут считаться как одно из значений столбца.